# What is `RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource` equivalent for python on Azure CloudService?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I'm running a python website, and want to use the `LocalStorage` on the WebRole of Azure CloudService.

And I can't get the path of the storage but using `RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource(name_of_storage)` in C#.

So what is the equivalent version of `RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource` in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with the problem with a simple environment variables "proxy" written by C#.

Thanks to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlining/2011/08/31/ruby-and-windows-azure-local-storage/).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            var path = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource(arg).RootPath;
            Console.WriteLine($"LocalRes_{arg}: {path}");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable($"LocalRes_{arg}", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
        }
```

It load the `LocalResource` configuration, then copy them to system environment variable.

It works for me.